# IE8 Different presentation of the same html from local drive, network drive and apache

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

my html/css works fine with chrome, FF and IE11. Also with IE8 when loaded locally from my harddrive.

When the same files are located in an networkdrive the css seems not to work properly. Colors and fonts are fine, but some div-containers are displayed at the wrong positions.

When i transport the files in the htdocs of an apache fonts and colors are fine, but other problems occur with the positioning. Strangly not the same as when started from the networkdrive. Some divs are now correct, others ar now misplaced.

I´m not able to find any pattern with this.

I can check the behaviour within ff and chrome with the build-in dev-tools. But i don´t know of any similar tool within IE8.

Any idea for my 1001 attemp to fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would one want to invest effort into supporting a browser from the stone ages that never really worked anyway? Those MS-browsers were broken by purpose. They are outdated. So stop supporting them so that users will _finally_ think about upgrading.

Comment: Even though I agree that we shouldn't support IE8. It is still a requirement for a lot of banks and companies with outdated systems to have IE8 as part of its specifications. I have had to add backwards compatibility to many projects for IE8. Also, IE8 is still supported by Microsoft, just not on outdated OS.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced different rendering modes for local and Internet servers so that web developers would break down in tears.

> If there’s no X-UA-Compatible value and site is in Local Intranet
>   security zone, it will be rendered in EmulateIE7 mode by default.

Add X-UA-Compatible header or META to force full IE8 standards mode.

Comment: It may also be necessary to add a [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to the page in order to ensure that it's loading in the Internet Zone, rather than a different zone, e.g. the Intranet zone.